# Mobile App from Web App, caching data/login

Tags: json, caching, cordova, titanium

I have a given Javascript browser application with login screen and data display screen. It does request JSON data via calls that are always the same (i.e. http://myserver.lol/api/getData?mobile), the data changing only slightly over time.

What I want is a mobile app for Android/iOS/Windows Phone/Blackberry, which
-> at best "caches" the whole web site (html/js...) in the app, so I don't have to rebuild the app whenever the web app changes;
-> provides some form of "auto-login"/"auto-form-fill", so the user does not have to give his credentials every time, and
-> some kind of long-term cache for the JSON data, so it is requested from server when a fast network connection (LTE/WLAN) is available, but taken from Cache on GSM or without connection.

Which Framework would allow to implement this the easiest? I am just now looking at the PhoneGap docs and the Titanium docs, but I guess I am overlooking something, or don't they provide an easy solution for this? Or perhaps you have an insider tip for me on another framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely handle this buy using both frameworks. I use only Phonegap / Cordova.

I would do this all by building the application with `Phonegap` together with `AngularJS`.

You can use templates in there, so you don't have to fetch the Ui from your server.

To cache data (user credentials or JSON data) I would just use the `localStorage` which is available   on all devices (see [here](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)).

I recommend [angularJS](http://angularjs.org) because it is a really great framework which helps you build Web-Applications really fast (but if you already have an existing application this might not be an option for you).

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: The app uses ExtJS. Thx for the tip with localStorage, I read "key/value pairs" and associated it with `KeyValuePair<String,String>`... but of course I can put a big JSON object there, until the memory is full :D How long does the localStorage last? Is it cleared only on request of my program, or could the OS/Browser/User interfere?

Comment: If you use Cordova / Phonegap the storage is persistent until the user clears the memory of the application or uninstalls the application. As far as I know there is no "easy" way of accessing the localStorage. Of course, if you connect your mobile phone to a computer you can (at least on iOS and Safari) run a developer-console and you have complete access to the Javascript running in your application. So if it is really a security issue you should probably work with some safety technics. But as far as it only concerns the user data I think its not that important.

Comment: It's not a safety issue. The question aimed at whether (a) the data I fetched before jumping on the plane into the jungle could be deleted on the way to free memory when I play memory-hungry games or reboot my phone (if I understand correctly, it is persistent, because localStorage is put in the Flash memory, not only RAM?), and/or (b) the user could "clear the cache" using existing OS functions (seems I have to add a button for localStorage.clear() :).

Comment: Yes! LocalStorage is persistent on reboot and application close. But it can be deleted by the user if he uninstalls the application or clears the data of the application.